# Scope of environment variables

Tags: environment-variables, services

I had thought previously, that environment variables are defined at process scope, and if exported, are propagated to child processes as well.

So, I wanted to find a single place to define my environment variables in single places and be accessible by:

1. User service, defined at ~/.config/systemd/user/start-up.service
2. Hyprland.conf file
3. ZSH shell

I'm using arch linux with sddm, hyprland, kitty terminal and zsh shell.
I have tried a number of solution, and the only working one was to define environment variables in hyprland.conf file (actually, in the external file, sourced by hyprland), and to have duplicate definition for two env variables needed by the the service in the service Environment field. I cannot use EnvironmentFile, since there is a mismatch in expected formats between hyprland and service files. I don't like this solution due to duplication.

But during my investigation I have found very surprising thing: all the environment variables defined in hyprland.conf are visible in zsh shell, the shell is not a child of hyprland process.

```
pstree
systemd─┬─NetworkManager───4*[{NetworkManager}]
        ├─dbus-daemon
   ==>  ├─kitty─┬─zsh───pstree
        │       └─2*[{kitty}]
        ├─polkitd───3*[{polkitd}]
        ├─rtkit-daemon───2*[{rtkit-daemon}]
        ├─sddm─┬─Xorg───2*[{Xorg}]
   ==>  │      ├─sddm-helper───Hyprland───4*[{Hyprland}]
        │      └─{sddm}
        ├─sh───sleep
        ├─ssh-agent
        ├─systemd─┬─(sd-pam)
        │         ├─dbus-daemon
        │         ├─gnome-keyring-d───4*[{gnome-keyring-d}]
        │         ├─pipewire───2*[{pipewire}]
        │         ├─pipewire-pulse───2*[{pipewire-pulse}]
        │         ├─wireplumber───6*[{wireplumber}]
        │         ├─2*[xdg-desktop-por───4*[{xdg-desktop-por}]]
        │         ├─xdg-document-po─┬─fusermount3
        │         │                 └─6*[{xdg-document-po}]
        │         └─xdg-permission-───3*[{xdg-permission-}]
        ├─systemd-journal
        ├─systemd-logind
        ├─systemd-timesyn───{systemd-timesyn}
        ├─systemd-udevd
        ├─upowerd───3*[{upowerd}]
        └─wpa_supplicant
```

So, I actually have two questions:

1. Is there a single place to define the environment variables (which should be defined at user level, not system wide) to be visible for user service, hyprland and shell
2. How it is possible, that variables defined at hyprland.conf are visible to its subling process?